# Request data seemingly dirty in multithreaded flask app

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, mod-wsgi, werkzeug

We are seeing a random error that seems to be caused by two requests' data getting mixed up. We receive a request for quoting shipping costs on an `Order`, but the request fails because the requested `Order` is not accessible by the requesting account. I'm looking for anyone who can provide an inkling on what might be happening here, I haven't found anything on google, the official flask help channels, or SO that looks like what we're experiencing.

We're deployed on AWS, with apache, mod_wsgi, 1 process, 15 threads, about 10 instances.

Here's the code that sends the email:

```py
    msg = f"Order ID {self.shipping.order.id} is not valid for this Account {self.user.account_id}"
    body = f"Error:<br/>{msg}<br/>Request Data:<br/>{request.data}<br/>Headers:<br/>{request.headers}"
    send_email(msg, body, "devops@*******.com")
    request_data = None
```

The problem is that in that scenario we email ourselves with the error and the request data, and the request data we're getting, in many cases, would've never landed in that particular piece of code. It can be a request from the frontend to get the current user's settings, for example, that make no reference to any orders, nevermind trying to get a shipping quote for it.

Comparing the application logs with apache's `access_log`, we see that, in all cases, we got two requests on the same instance, one requesting the quoting, and another which is the request that is actually getting logged. We don't know whether these two requests are processed by the same thread in rapid succession, or by different threads, but they come so close together that I think the latter is much more probable. We have no way of univocally tying the `access_log` entries with the application logging, so far, so we don't know which one of the requests is logging the error, but the fact is that we're getting routed to a view that does not correspond to the request's content (i.e., we're not sure whether the quoting request is getting the wrong request object, or if the other one is getting routed to the wrong view).

Another fact that is of interest is that we use graphql, so part of the routing is done *after* flask/werkzeug do theirs, but the body we get from `flask.request` at the moment the error shows up does not correspond with the graphql function/mutation that gets executed. But this also happens in views mapped directly through flask. The user is looked up by the `flask-login` workflow at the very beginning, and it corresponds to the "bad" request (i.e., the one not for quoting).

Comment: did you find solution ? I met same problem in our production environment

Answer (score 0):

The actual issue was a bug on one of `python-graphql`'s libraries (`promise`), not on Flask, werkzeug or apache. It was not the request data that was "moving" to a different thread, but a different thread trying to resolve the promise for a query that was supposed to be handled elsewhere.